# Karma not picking the changes, have to run tests twice

Tags: intellij-idea, jasmine, karma-runner

I am running **Jasmine** tests on **Karma** (latest, 0.12.14) from **IntelliJ IDEA** (latest, 13.1.2) on **OS X**.

IntelliJ just uses Karma plugin that points to my karma installation: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma`

The problem is that Karma watcher doesn't pick new changes from JS files. When I **run tests again**, everything **is fine**. It's not a huge issue (they run pretty fast), but it's annyoing to always run tests twice after you do a change.

Anybody experienced similar issue?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: I also have same issue.  I can verify that the test gets executed on the "pre-change" version of the files.  ie: if I have the auto-watch toggle on, and I add a console.log, the tests run automatically (because it detects I made a change), but no console.log.  If I then manually re-run the tests, I see the console.log

Answer (score 7):

Add the following property to your karma.conf.js file:

```
usePolling: true
```

I put it after the autoWatch flag.

Reference: [AutoWatch doesn't work #895](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/895)

Comment: Didn't work in my case. I thing the issue might not be within Karma, but in IntelliJ

Comment: This worked for me on Webstorm 2016.2.3 which was running my entire test suite twice.

Answer (score 6):

Finally got this to work.  This is [a known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21308) when using Karma in IntelliJ with build tools like Webpack / Gulp / etc...  and that the post-processed files are outside of the files that Karma is directly serving.

The workaround is to manually modify the IntelliJ config in this file: `...\plugins\js-karma\js_reporter\karma-intellij\lib\intellijRunner.js`

At or near line `#75` in the `runWithConfig()` method, change the `refresh` property --> `true`.

See [this comment for details](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21308#comment=27-1812539)

Had this issue in both IntelliJ and Webstorm and fixed both the same way.

Comment: Indeed that did the trick for me on WebStorm 2016.3 (/w autoWatch=false noPolling and "safe write".

Answer (score 5):

In the case of using IntelliJ IDEA, maybe try
Preferences > General > Uncheck "safe write"

Comment: This worked in IntelliJ 2019.1.1, though the option has moved to Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Use Safe Write

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if question is still actual, but i found a solution (or just a workaround).

I changed this file `C:\Users\MyUser\.IntelliJIdea14\config\plugins\js-karma\js_reporter\karma-intellij\lib\intellij.conf.js` a little bit here:

```
config.singleRun = false;
var originalAutoWatch = config.autoWatch;
//config.autoWatch = false; <-- this line
config.autoWatchBatchDelay = 0;
```

For sure the plugin maintainers had some reason to add this line, but for me this worked fine enough (there were isolated crashes I can't reproduce).

Comment: Works great! I'd also recommend to comment the next line (autoWatchBatchDelay) so that the default of 250ms is kept. This makes karma wait 250ms for other file changes before running the tests again.

Comment: this did not work for me.  after making a change to a file (src file or spec file), the autowatch is triggered, and the tests re-run -- but the change isn't picked up (ie: if I fixed a test, it still says the test failed).  However, when I hit re-run tests manually again, then it says the test passed.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about older versions of intelij but I am using 2016.3 (the latest version at the time of writing this) and it all works OK assuming karma config has `autoWatch: true`.
Having exactly the same problem all I have to do was to switch on `Toggle auto-test` in intelij and all started working fine without any other change.

Answer (score 1):

Please check autoWatch property in karma config file set to TRUE.

Comment: It has been set to true all the time. It actually prints watcher statements to console.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are using Sublime Text 3 then set "atomic_save": false in your user settings as it also causes issues with watches. see [here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/895)

Answer (score 0):

**Macros** worked for me. After trying [usePolling: true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24122433/3700366), [modifying the intellijRunner.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42074292/3700366), and [unchecking Safe Write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26407061/3700366) I still had to save or run tests twice to catch the changes.

Made a compound macro to both Save and Run File and Save and Re-Run Test. Then I overwrote each commands' shortcut via Keymap.

[How to bind multiple actions to a shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948061/how-to-bind-multiple-actions-to-a-shortcut)

[screenshot of macro: Save and Run test at cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAYu6.png)

[screenshot of macro: Save and Re-run last test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43y6h.png)

[screenshot of Keymap for macros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFlp2.png)