# How to bind multiple actions to a shortcut

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

Each time I finished editing a Java class, I want to : Organize imports, Reformat code and Rearrange code. I have to hit 3 keyboard shortcuts.

Is there a way to assign a chain of actions to a single shortcut ?

I am using IntelliJ 14.1.5.

Comment: Have you tried creating a Macro? https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/recording-macros.html and assigning it a shortcut: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/binding-macros-with-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Comment: @Bohuslav Burghardt : Thank you very much. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can record a macro consisting of the actions you want to perform and assign a shortcut to that macro.

The process is described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html). For the sake of completeness, here are the steps from these online guides (credit goes to Jetbrains):

> **To record a macro**
>
> - On the main menu, choose Edit | Macros | Start Macro Recording. From that moment on, all your recordable actions are recorded.
> - When you are done with the procedure, choose Edit | Macros | Stop Macro Recording.
> - In the Enter Macro Name dialog, specify the name of the new macro, and click OK. If the macro is intended for temporary use only, you can
>     leave the name blank.
>
> **To bind a macro with a keyboard shortcut**
>
> - Open the Settings dialog and click Keymap.
> - Create a new keymap Run/Debug Configuration: PHP Script or select an editable keymap from the list of keymaps.
> - Expand the Macros node and select the macro for which a keyboard shortcut should be created.
> - Right-click on the macro and choose Add Keyboard Shortcut in the context menu.
> - In the Enter Keyboard Shortcut dialog, press the keys to be used as a shortcut. The keystrokes are immediately reflected in the First
>     Stroke field. Optionally, select the Second stroke check box and
>     specify the second stroke. As you press the keys, the Preview field
>     displays the keystrokes you pressed, and the Conflicts field displays
>     warnings, if the keystrokes are already in use.
> - Click OK using the mouse pointer to create a shortcut and bind it with the macro.
> - Click Apply to save the settings.

Comment: Is there anyway to tweak timings on macro? When I record macro actions, Intellij 15 does not play them in order I executed them, but simultaneously... Which makes the feature almost useless.

Say I want to make 'gulp build' and 'reload changes classes' 10 seconds after frontend finished copying and building resources. How do I achieve this?